# Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, memory

I am facing this problem since more than a month, here is what I see when I run java on command line:

```
$ java -Xmx1300m 
Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

If I run with less memory it works fine

```
$ java -Xmx1240m Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class) or java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file) ..... .....
```

I spent a week trying to debug this and nothing worked. Finally I had my IT support guys replace the laptop. This happened a month ago on 10/23. Now, after a month, the same problem is back on my new system.

My system configuration is:

> Win 7 Enterprise (64-bit), Service Pack 1. Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M
>   CPU @ 2.80GHz 8.00 GB RAM

```
Java: java version "1.5.0_20" Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_20-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_20-b02, mixed mode)
```

We are a team of about 30 guys here and I am the only one facing this. All others have almost the same config and working fine for them.

An important observation is Java works fine for some time and then this problem appears once it appears it doesn't go away, even if I re-install java.

I faced this issue the 3rd time after the IT support guys re-imaged by laptop. It worked for a month and now the same problem is back.

Everybody is completely clueless. I have started using 2 laptops now. :-)

Comment: Have you tried the 64-bit version of Java?

Comment: Do you have other large processes running? A database server? A web server? What's the memory load on your laptop? How big is your page file?  Are you _really_ running the 32-bit version of Java (that's almost surely your problem if you are).  Why are you running Java 5?  It's obsolete.

Comment: Yes and it works but our product uses 32-bit Java and I cannot make that decision as everyone uses the same.

Comment: I installed JDK 64bit instead of 32bit.

Answer (score 16):

Anyway, here is how to fix it:

Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:

Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS

Variable value: -Xmx512M

taken from [this link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap-resolved.88119/)

Comment: See also http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tips-and-workarounds-android-readme/#could-not-create-java-virtual-machine-error if you are using Cordova

Answer (score 15):

Eureka ! Finally I found a solution on this.

This is caused by Windows update that stops any 32-bit processes from consuming more than 1200 MB on a 64-bit machine. The only way you can repair this is by using the System Restore option  on Win 7.

Start >> All Programs >> Accessories >> System Tools >> System Restore.

And then restore to a date on which your Java worked fine. This worked for me. What is surprising here is Windows still pushes system updates under the name of "Critical Updates" even when you disable all windows updates. ^&*%)#** Windows :-)

Answer (score 8):

This might also occur if you are running on 64-bit Machine with 32-bit JVM (JDK), switch it to 64-bit JVM. Check your (Right Click on My Computer --> Properties) Control Panel\System and Security\System --> Advanced System Settings -->Advanced Tab--> Environment Variables --> JAVA_HOME...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks.I changed heap space from 2000MB to 1024MB and it worked...

Comment: how to change heap space?

Comment: how to change head space?

Answer (score 1):

I've just seen this problem myself, Jboss AS7 with jdk1.5.0_09. Update System Property JAVA_HOME to jdk1.7+ to fix (I'm using jdk1.7.0_67).

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is a 64bit, all you need to do is uninstall your Java x86 version and install a 64bit version. I had the same problem and this worked. Nothing further needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

you can do update the User path as inside 
_JAVA_OPTIONS : -Xmx512M
Path : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\bin
for now it is working         /
                            /

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it may happen that you run multiple applications on the same java VM. In Case you have tried all the other solutions described above and it didnt work. Try Running your process by running it on a newly created java VM by passing vmargs

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=10049,suspend=n .
```

Here address is what the vm takes.