# Installation of elastic search 5.1.1 in windows 7 32bit RAM:4gb pc

Tags: elasticsearch, jvm, heap-size

when i try to open the bat file of elastic search in command prompt it showing a following errors

Error occurred during initialization of VM

> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

Please Can anyone help me in sorting out this problem clearly because i am new to this environment ??

Comment: is that the whole error ? Make sure you've got `Java` before you deploy ES.

Comment: yeah actually i have java jdk 1.7 but i dont know,to what heap size i have to configure in that in such way it doesnt any errors in commandprompt?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the latest version of the `jdk`.

Check it out [here](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#show_jvm) from the requirement matrix. Scroll down to Elasticsearch 5.1.x within the `Product and JVM` section where it says that you got to have [Oracle JVM 1.8u40+](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

**EDIT**:

What if you run your jvm as such, by increasing your `heapsize`:

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=512m
```

or what if you set it from the the `Environment Variables`:

Go to `Start` > `Control Panel` > `System` > `Advanced system settings` > `advanced(tab)` > `Environment Variables` → `System Variables` → `New` and then the following values:

```
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307923/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-ob) could be helpful!

Comment: i tried with oracle jvm 1.8 too then also it was showing the same error..

Comment: To write this command i have to go to java control panel and in that in runtime parameters i have give this heap size configuration right..

Comment: sry for late reply i have updated the settings as per your answer now i am getting new errors like

Comment: Like error occurred during installation of vm and could not reserve enough space for 2097152kb object heap

Comment: PLS do provide with any solution to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Could you alter your 'ELASTICSEARCH DIR'/config/jvm.options?

Try altering this:

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```

into

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g
```

or even lower (like 512m)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. Use latest version of [java8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Goto config folder and open elasticsearch.yml file then do below changes.

Uncomment the cluster.name and node.name in elasticsearch.yml like below and give your own cluster and node name.

```
cluster.name: ESCluster

node.name: ESNode
```

3.Change heap size in jvm.options

```
-Xms1g

-Xmx1g
```

4. Goto bin folder then run elasticsearch.bat